# How to change color of GeocoderAutoCompleteView cancel button - Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

How do I change the color of the X from black to white in the GeocoderAutoCompleteView?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create your own geocoding widget if you want to tint the clear button color. It is [hardcoded in the view](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/libandroid/lib/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/geocoder/ui/GeocoderAutoCompleteView.java#L62-L80) currently. I've [opened an issue on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/issues/195) to expose an API which will allow you to get the drawable and customize it.